# Superior Will vs Auras that daze/stun, or: Order of Operations for Start of Turn effects

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, conditions, aura

Monsters that have auras often have text that says "If a creature starts their turn within the aura, then {something happens}."  In this case, the monster's aura *dazes* or *stuns* anyone who starts their turn within the aura (until end of the following turn, save ends, or whatever-- it doesn't matter for this question).

The **Superior Will** feat allows characters who are dazed or stunned to make a saving throw against such a status effect at the start of their turn, even if that daze or stun does not normally allow a saving throw.

Does Superior Will happen first, and then the daze or stun effect is applied, meaning they do not get an immediate save because they didn't have the status effect yet? Or does the aura give the stun at the beginning of the turn, and since we are still at "the beginning of the turn", Superior Will comes into play, granting an immediate saving throw to end the daze/stun?

What is the order of operations here?

(In our recent game, we agreed that you do get an immediate saving throw, but I'd like to know what the real answer should be)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The order of operations is your choice.

> **Any Order**: The creature can choose the order in which things happen at the start of its turn. For instance, if the creature has regeneration and is taking ongoing damage, it can choose to take the ongoing damage and then use its regeneration or the other way around.
>
> -- "The Start of a Turn", *Rules Compendium* p.197

So yes, you can eat the aura and then try to Superior Will your way out of it.